# Read STDIN while waiting for remote data; terminate when remote data is downloaded

Tags: perl, concurrency, parallel-processing, stdin

I have a simple perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use utf8;
binmode( STDOUT, ":utf8" );
$|++;

my $localBookmarks = {
    a => "local bookmark A",
    b => "local bookmark B",
    c => "local bookmark C",
};
print Dumper $localBookmarks;

my $remoteBookmarks = getRemoteBookmarks();
print Dumper $remoteBookmarks;

print "choose a bookmark: ";
my $answer = <STDIN>;
print "You want: $answer";
# process $answer...

sub getRemoteBookmarks
{
    # Net::SSH::Perl connection; exec command; parse it; return it
    # lets just simulate this
    sleep( 5 );
    return { d => "remote bookmark D", e => "remote bookmark E" };
}
```

The output is:

```
$ perl test.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => 'local bookmark B',
          'a' => 'local bookmark A',
          'c' => 'local bookmark C'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'd' => 'remote bookmark D',
          'e' => 'remote bookmark E'
        };
choose a bookmark:
```

Of course after `print Dumper $localBookmarks` there is a silence for 5 seconds.

Is it possible to read `<STDIN>` right after printing "local bookmarks", while waiting for "remote bookmarks"? In case I know that local bookmarks is all I need this time (and I dont have to wait few seconds for the download). Otherwise, when "remote bookmarks" are downloaded, current `<STDIN>` should be terminated, downloaded bookmarks should be printed, and - again - at the bottom there should be `<STDIN>`. Is this possible with perl?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways you can do this.  One of the more obvious ways is to spawn a thread to do the remote work, and, after you read from STDIN, and, assuming you can't find the answer there, join the thread (to ensure it's done) and check there.  The thread would need to do everything you already have in `getRemoteBookmarks`, as well as erase the "choose a bookmark" line (usually printing `"\r", ' ' x 60, "\r"` will suffice), print out the dumper of the new group, and print out the new "choose a bookmark" entry.

There's a bit of extra finnagling required to stop the thread from printing anything out if the choice is already made, sharing variables between threads, etc., but that's the general idea.

Another option is to handle this through event processing.  You'd basically have both the input (using the event handling in [Term::ReadLine](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine) - see [Term::ReadLine::Event](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Event) for how to do this with various event modules) and your ssh going on at the same time.  What this avoids is some of the thread sharing and such, since everything is happening in the same thread.

Either way, your script is going to be much less simple, and you may really be better off just printing out "Gathering information, please wait" at the beginning, gathering all of the options, both local and remote, and then printing out the options.  From a cost/benefit perspective, that is.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example using [`IPC::Open3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3) to open a single child process that reads the remote bookmarks. When the child is finished it will store the bookmarks in a file (the alternative would be to use threads, pipes or filehandles to communicate, but I think that would complicate the program slightly). The parent will get a `CHLD` signal when the child process terminates, this will cause the parent to exit its input loop and read the remote bookmarks from disk. Then the parent reenters the input loop:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use IPC::Open3;
use Symbol qw(gensym);
use Storable qw(retrieve);

local $SIG{CHLD} = sub {
    die "\nBackground process finished..\n";
};

my $child1 = start_reading_remote_bookmarks(  );
my $local_bookmarks = {
    a => "local bookmark A",
    b => "local bookmark B",
    c => "local bookmark C",
};
print Dumper $local_bookmarks;
eval {
    run_input_loop();
};
if ($@) {
    print "\n";
    my $remote_bookmarks = retrieve('bookmarks.dat');
    print Dumper $remote_bookmarks;
    run_input_loop();
}

sub run_input_loop {
    while (1) {
        print "Choose a bookmark: ";
        chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>);
        say "You want: $answer";
        # process $answer...
    }
}

sub start_reading_remote_bookmarks {
    my $cmd = 'get_bookmarks.pl';
    my $cherr = gensym;
    my $pid = open3( my $chin, my $chout, $cherr, $cmd );
    return { pid => $pid, kid_in => $chin, kid_out => $chout, kid_err => $cherr };
}
```

where `get_bookmarks.pl` is

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable qw(store);

sleep 5;
my $fn = 'bookmarks.dat';
store { d => "remote bookmark D", e => "remote bookmark E" }, $fn;
```